# reload on button click in

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

Here is my aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_updateClinicVisit" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupClinicVisitEntry2" DefaultButton="bt_editClinicVisit_submit"  Style="display:none">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button AutoPostBack="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="AddMedicationChange" ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Add Med Change" OnClick="AddMedicationChange_Click" />
            <asp:Panel ID="AddNewMedicationPanel" runat="server">
                <asp:TextBox ID="NewDrugName" OnTextChanged="NewDrugName_TextChanged" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="NewDrugNameAutoCompleteExtender"
                    runat="server"
                    TargetControlID="NewDrugName"
                    MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                    EnableCaching="false"
                    CompletionSetCount="1"
                    CompletionInterval="500"
                    ServiceMethod="GetDrugs">
                </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
                <asp:DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged="NewDrugChange_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="NewDrugChange" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Drug +</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Drug -</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Dose ↑</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Dose ↓</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Button AutoPostBack="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="SubmitMedChange" runat="server" Text="Add to Visit" OnClick="SubmitMedicationChange_Click" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="updateClinicModalPopupExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="bt_editClinicVisit_dummy"
                PopupControlID="pnl_updateClinicVisit" CancelControlID="bt_editClinicVisit_cancel"
                DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>          
 </asp:Panel>
```

For some reason my page is reloading when I click the "AddnewMdication" and "SubmitMedChange" buttons. When I have the `AutoPostBack=false UseSubmitBehavior=false`, the events fire and then the page reloads. If I don't have these attributes then the page reloads before the events even fire. How do I get AJAX functionality within this modal?

Comment: Have you added the script manager to your page?

Comment: yes, I have added a script manager to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your `Button`s as an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`. You can do this by adding in the `Triggers` section and declaring the `UpdatePanel` as a conditional update.

For example

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"
    UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>        
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="AddMedicationChange" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SubmitMedChange" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>    
    <ContentTemplate>        
        <%-- Your code here --%>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What this should do is to explicitly declare that those two buttons as being Async.

If this doesn't work, will you please post the relevant code to your two button OnClick events? `AddMedicationChange_Click` and `SubmitMedicationChange_Click`

If you try to interact with controls outside of the `UpdatePanel` in your code-behind during an asyncpostback, odd things can start to happen.